# Equation system on Z[x]

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can we solve this equation system when $n=2,3,4,\cdots \ $ is given?
$$ F(x)+F((2^n-1)x) = (G(x))^nx^g $$
$$ 2F(2^{n-1}x) = (H(x))^nx^h $$
While $F,G,H \in \mathbb{Z}[x]. g,h \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: What's being solved for? You specify that `$n$` is given, but surely that can't be all?

Comment: I wanted to solve for all $(F,G,H,g,h)$.

Comment: Anybody can write down a system of equations, and ask how to solve it. What led you to write down this particular system? Why should anyone be interested in it? 

Comment: Mmm.. It's about this problem: for any $a+b=k^n$, we have a $l$ such that $F(a)+F(b)=l^n$, solve for $F$. Certainly $F \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: And, $a,b>0$. $n$ is given. "we have" means "we can find".